# Error finding element using uiautomatorviewer, appium and python

Tags: python, appium, uiautomatorviewer

[image: Screenshot of UIAUTOMATORVIEWER]

I am trying to write a python code to verify for the presence of `.mp3` and corresponding `.json` file in the dropbox.

```
dropboxmp3txt = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView/android.view.View/android.widget.TextView[contains(@index, "1")]')
print dropboxmp3txt.text
```

This gives me the output :

`abc2016-05-05, 10.38.26.mp3`  Which is perfectly fine!!!

I need the similar xpath to find the `.json` text. The one which is below the `.mp3` , in the figure.

I tried doing :

```
dropboxmp3txt = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView/android.view.View[0]/android.widget.TextView[contains(@index, "1")]')
print dropboxmp3txt.text
dropboxjsontxt = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.TextView[contains(@index, "1")]')
print dropboxjsontxt.text
```

But, that gave me an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropboxshare.py", line 136, in test_1_view_checkbox
    dropboxtxt = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView/android.view.View[0]/android.widget.TextView[contains(@index, "1")]')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 258, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

There is no ID specified for the 2 texts.. Only thing that is unique in both is the extension (.mp3 and .json)..

How can I retrieve these 2 texts ??

The texts
`abc2016-05-5,10.38.26.mp3`
and
`abc2016-05-5,10.38.26.json`
I can't enter directly..
like:
`xpath("//android.widget.ListView/android.view.View/android.widget.TextView[@index='1' and @text='abc2016-05-05, 10.38.26.mp3' ]")`
`xpath("//android.widget.ListView/android.view.View/android.widget.TextView[@index='1' and @text='abc2016-05-05, 10.38.26.json' ]")`

Because, some other `.mp3` and `.json` might come during the next run and occupy those place..
It changes during runtime.. I need to know what text is present in that location first.
How can I retrieve it..
ANY IDEA ???

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you are trying might be conflicting.
Try with `//android.widget.ImageView/../android.widget.TextView[1]`

It will return two elements, so use `find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: @Karthik : i believe pr4bh4sh is suggesting to create and use the `List` of similar elements.

Comment: `List <WebElement> counter = driver.findElements(By.id("com.android.textview"));`
`for(int index= 0 ;  index < counter.size() ;index++)`
`{`
`System.out.println(counter.get(index).getText());`
`}`   Something like this in JAVA right ?!!

Comment: As in ```List <WebElement> counter = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)); for(int index= 0 ; index < counter.size() ;index++) { System.out.println(counter.get(index).getText()); }```